# How to show that these two lines are perpendicular?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle AEE'$ be an isosceles triangle with $\angle EAE'=90^\circ$ such that $AE=AE'$ and such that $A$, $E$ and $E'$ lie on the circle $c_1$. Let $\triangle ADD'$ be an isosceles triangle with $\angle DAD'=90^\circ$ such that $AD=AD'$ and such that $A$, $D$ and $D'$ lie on the circle $c_2$. Let $S$ be the intersection of the lines $DE'$ and $DE'$.

The picture below summarizes the situation: [image]

I want to prove that $D'E \perp DE'$, i.e. $\angle ESE'=90^\circ$.

I have already shown that $\triangle AED'$ and $\triangle AE'D$ are congruent. How do I continue from here? I hope that it is possible to avoid using a coordinate system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $S$ lie on intersection of circles ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll modify the question.

Comment: Then you're done : $\angle EAE' = 90^{\circ} \implies EE'$ is diameter of circle $c_1 \implies \angle ESE' = 90^{\circ}$ since it is a semicircle angle.

Comment: How do you know that S lies on the intersection of the circles (i.e. what's the proof) ? As in above comment, *if* you do then then the result follows trivially.

Comment: @ganeshie8, write down that as an answer. +1

Comment: @ganeshie8. Thank you for your help. But for arguments sake, let's assume that S does NOT lie on the intersection of c1 and c2. How can you prove this? And what do you mean by semicircle angle?

Comment: I think the circles are a distraction: any three non co-linear points lie on a circle (and form a triangle). If you can show the two lines are perpendicular it follows that S lies on both circles too (by same argument in comment above). I would (will) try a proof of perpendicularity ignoring the circles.

Comment: Nice question! What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @Rainier van Es.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to prove without using the fact that $S$ lies on intersection of circles :

$$ \begin{align} &\angle ADD' =  \angle AD'D = 45^{\circ} \\~\\ \end{align} $$ 
$$\begin{align}& \overline{AE} \cong \overline{AE'} \\ &\angle EAD' \cong \angle E'AD \\
&\overline{AD'} \cong \overline{AD} \\ &\implies \triangle AED' \cong \triangle AE'D ~~\text{By SAS}\\&
\angle ADE' \cong \angle AD'E ~\color{gray}{\text{By CPCTC}} \\
 \end{align}$$

[image]
$$\begin{align}&\implies \angle DD'S  = 45+x ~~\text{and}~~\angle D'DS = 45-x \\~\\ &\implies \angle DSD' = 90 \\&~~\color{gray}{\text{By triangle sum property in }  \triangle DSD'
}\end{align} $$

Comment: I don't follow the second line.

Comment: I'll attach a pic, one sec :)

Comment: Thanks for the pic. To be happy with the proof though I'd like to see the proof of congruency, specifically that DE' = D'E.

Comment: The OP has already proved it I think, but I'll add the proof anyways - still working on it

Comment: OK, two sides and the included angle. E'AD' = EAE' + 90 = E'AD

Comment: check it out now @TomCollinge

Comment: Yes, +1 for the answer. .. and the circles are a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a terse proof with complex numbers. Take $A$ to be the origin and let the coordinates of $D,E,D',E'$ be $iz,w,z,i w$ respectively. Then be construction we have isosceles triangles formed by the points $\{0,z,iz\}$ and $\{0,w,iw\}$. The angle formed by $DE'$ and $D'E$ is then found as the argument of $\dfrac{z-w}{i(z-w)}=-i$, and is thus $90^\circ$.

Comment: How do know that the argument equals $(z-w)/(i(z-w))$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the intersection of $DS$ and $AD'.$
Then $\angle PD'S = \angle AD'E= \angle ADE' = \angle ADP,$
using the fact that $\triangle AD'E \cong \triangle ADE'$. 
Also $\angle APD=\angle SPD'$ since they are a pair of vertical angles.
Two angles of $\triangle APD$ are congruent to corresponding angles in $\triangle SPD'$,
so the two triangles are similar, hence $\angle D'SP=\angle PAD = 90^\circ$,
hence  $D'E \perp DE'.$